# Exit from Android application not working

Tags: android, dialog

In my Android application I want exit from the application when I back pressed from HomeAcitvity. But it always goes to Loginactivity when I back pressed.

Below code used in HomeAcitvity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Exit"); // Sets title for your alertbox

        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit ?"); // Message to be displayed on alertbox

        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logout_icon); // Icon for your alertbox

/* When positive (yes/ok) is clicked */
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

/* When negative (No/cancel) button is clicked*/
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Before you open HomeActivity finish the login activity  like:                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),HomeActivity.class);
                                            getActivity().startActivity(intent); finish();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the login activity after call intent homeactivity `finish();`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and the activity you need to get exit from

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
              .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
              .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       finish();
                       System.exit(0);
              }
       }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this at your code

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
 moveTaskToBack(true);
 android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
 System.exit(1);
 finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before launching Home activity, clear the stack like below.

```
Intent intent_home = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent_home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent_home);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code while launching your home activity from login activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code will clear the backstack of all the activities that were previously opened. And will launch the HomeActivity with no previous/parent activity. And you would not require to override the onBackPress method also.

Answer (score 0):

System.exit() and finish() are superficially similar above android 4.4.2. Prior to that, System.exit() would not invoke onActivityResult() method while finish() would. Otherwise, they both end the current activity. Also, finish() seems to work faster than System.exit().

I think you need to write this:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0)                   // you may also use finish() or nothing as per your requirements
```